# Как распознать функцию

Tags: python, list, numpy

Есть две функции - каким способом можно определить тип функции или смещение на какой то бок? Тоесть чтобы можно было сказать, если есть значение равное столько то, то это функция примерно вида такого...

```
from matplotlib import pyplot as plt
import numpy as np

x1 = np.linspace(0, 12, 100)
y1 = np.sin(x)*np.exp(-x/4)

x2 = np.arange(0,3*np.pi,0.1)
y2 = np.sin(x)
```

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: Посчитай центроид набора точек.

Answer (score 2):

Для подбора функции под известный набор значений можно использовать функцию [`scipy.optimize.curve_fit`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/generated/scipy.optimize.curve_fit.html). В качестве аргументов она принимает функцию вида `fn(x, p1, p2, ..., pn)` и ищет такой набор значений параметров `p1,...,pn`, чтобы `fn` оказалась ближе всего к заданному набору. Помимо набора параметров `curve_fit` возвращает ковариационную матрицу, которая даёт возможность оценить ошибку аппроксимации.

К сожалению, `curve_fit` не умеет угадывать вид функции, которую использовать для аппроксимации. Это работа пользователя. `curve_fit` будет искать параметры даже в том случае, когда предложенная функция совсем не похожа на заданную.

Пример.

Попробуем аппроксимировать первый график простым синусом.

```
import scipy.optimize as spo
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

x1 = np.linspace(0, 12, 100)
y1 = np.sin(x1)*np.exp(-x1/4)

# Подбор функции как A*sin(a(x-dx))
def guess_sin(x, A, a, dx):
    return A*np.sin(a*(x-dx))

params, covariancve = spo.curve_fit(guess_sin, x1, y1)
err = np.sqrt(np.diag(covariancve))
print(params, err)
```

Получится вот что:

```
(array([ 0.30108858,  0.98160253, -0.17234397]),
 array([0.02448288, 0.02523105, 0.17641344]))
```

В первой строке идёт вектор параметров, во второй - вектор ошибок. По третьему параметру видно, что аппроксимация так себе - величина ошибки больше самого значения. Построим график полученной аппроксимации:

```
y1_sin = guess_sin(x1, *params)
plt.plot(x1,y1)
plt.plot(x1, y1_sin, ls='--')
```

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Видно, что приближение несколько не удалось.

Теперь попробуем аппроксимировать другой функцией:

```
# Подбор функции как A*sin(a(x-d1))*(b/x)
def guess_sin_invx(x, A, a, d1, b):
    return A*np.sin(a*(x-d1))*(b/x)
# Игнорируем первые две точки, так как будет деление на 0
params, covariancve = spo.curve_fit(guess_sin_invx, x1[2:], y1[2:])
err = np.sqrt(np.diag(covariancve))
print(params, err)
y1_sinexp2 = guess_sin_invx(x1[2:], *params)
plt.plot(x1,y1)
plt.plot(x1[2:], y1_sinexp2, ls='--')
```

Результат получится такой:

```
(array([1.21971316, 1.03866358, 0.23717369, 0.84078164]),
 array([inf, inf, inf, inf]))
```

Матрица ошибок вообще не получилась из-за слишком больших чисел вблизи нуля. Поэтому качество аппроксимации можно оценивать только на глаз.

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Как выглядит вектор ошибок, когда аппроксимация идеальна:

```
def guess_sinexp(x, A, a, d1, b):
    return A*np.sin(a*(x-d1))*np.exp(-b*x)
params, covariancve = spo.curve_fit(guess_sinexp, x1, y1)
err = np.sqrt(np.diag(covariancve))
print(params, err)
```

Вывод `(array([1.00000000e+00, 1.00000000e+00, 1.95903459e-09, 2.50000000e-01]), array([3.87359349e-10, 8.04285095e-11, 2.16429930e-10, 1.29385134e-10]))`

Видите, какие крохотные ошибки? То, что ошибки порядка 1е-10 означает, что вид функции угадан точно.

Comment: @nik_golunov что вы хотите узнать? Вид функции установлен точно. Подобраны параметры функции, можно вычислять значения. Смещение определяет параметр `d1`. Он равен 1.2е-9, то есть практически нуль. Следовательно, функция не смещена.